# EaselJS - Storing Shape Graphics in Database

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I'm using EaselJS for a project, and have the need to store the details of various 'Shape' objects in a database, so that they can be re-drawn at another time. 
My project has the 'Stage' set up so that I can drag-draw a box, which is saved into the database when completed. I intend to make it usable for drawing polygons also. 
My database has a table in it called 'polyshapes', which stores the Shape.id, Shape.name, Shape.x, Shape.y, Shape.rotation. It also has a field called 'graphics' where I can store some sort of text string representing the Shape.graphics object. 
When I draw a box, I'm able to store a string of the 'graphics' using: JSON.stringify(Myshape.graphics).

When I load this shape from the database, I create a new createjs.Shape() object, and then use Myshape.graphics = JSON.parse(graphicsString) to load the graphics. 
Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, as it doesn't load the required functions within the object.

I have also tried just individually updating some specific graphics attributes such as 'command', '_instructions', '_stroke', '_strokeStyle'. But I still can get the required graphic to re-draw.

Ideally, I'd only need to store the 'instructions' attribute of the Shape.graphics when I drag-draw it, and then when loading from the DB, I would just use a method to re-create those graphics when provided with the 'instructions' data. However I can't seem to see a suitable method for doing this.

I have also looked into the decodePath() graphics method. This would be useful, except that there doesn't appear to be an inverse method 'encodePath()' to allow me to serialize it in the first place.

How can I store the Shape.graphics data in a database, and then recall it later to rebuild a new Shape() object?

Thanks, 
Hugh.